# reset html5 canvas game

Tags: html, canvas, reset

At the moment I currently have a game that draws the asteroids and the background, score etc and once the ship hits a asteroid it takes the user to the gameover screen and when they hit the play again button I want the game to reset and not start from when it just hit the asteroid.

```
function playGame() {
clearCtxMenu();
clearCtxGameOver();
drawBg();
startLoop();
score = 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown',checkKeyDown,false);
document.addEventListener('keyup',checkKeyUp,false);
}
```

this loads everything into the game and clears the images in the menu/gameover screen.

```
function gameOver() {
stopLoop();
drawPlayAgain();
drawMenu();
ctxGameOver.fillText("Score: " + score, 320, 160);
ctxGameOver.fillText("Highscore: " + highScore, 300, 180);
}
```

the game over function which calls when the asteroid is hit.

I have it set that once you hit the play again button it calls the playGame function but I want it to start from the beginning and not where it had just finished.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone whos after the question, I just emptied the array, for example ArrayName = [];

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more clear (and since I can't comment yet):

In the w3c schools game tutorial located here (http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp), I had a question about how to reset the game in a single page application and found this question.  The above answer is right, but for me I didn't understand it well enough to have the 'ah ha' moment for a bit.

So, with an example it might help others to understand where the fix is.  Look at the following code:

```
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
 }
```

The line "var myObstacles = [];" holds the location of the obstacles, if it is reset the game will have to make new ones. Thus 'resetting' the game.  The rest is taken care of by the code in the tutorial.

Hope this helps someone.